# How to change the channel for android wifi-direct connection?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm currently utilizing Wi-Fi Direct to transfer packets between an Android Google Pixel 6a and a Raspberry Pi 4. The Wi-Fi operates on the 5GHz frequency, and the Android phone serves as the group owner. I'm interested in knowing how to alter the channel on the Android phone without having to root the device.

Any help is appreciated!!